# Is there a way to create shortcuts on sublime for words used often?

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimetext

For instance, I use System.out.println a lot is there a way I can create a much smaller term that will automatically include the whole command. Similar to how when you write main you can tab into the whole "public static void main(String[] args)". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using [snippets](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#snippets), [`.sublime-completions`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#completion-files) files, or customized [plugins](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#plugins). See the full documentation on completions [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html). The unofficial docs also have a [completions](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/completions.html) section.

The following snippet will create `System.out.println()` from the `sop` shortcut, with the cursor between the parentheses `()`:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
System.out.println($0)
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>sop</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.java</scope>
</snippet>
```